# Just how accurate is this XKCD comic about building a real-life periodic table with cubes made up of each element?

Tags: elements, periodic-table

I was reading the book “What If?” by Randall Munroe and this part was very intriguing to me. He answered the question in the title and I was curious if his answer was realistic, and if not, which parts he got wrong.

This is the [comic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMleNES9aYo0gQcbgGS_crXJ0DW_6dQz/view?usp=drivesdk) I'm talking about. I'm especially curious if Astatine is really *that* dangerous.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. This guy is generally very good with his estimates. Astatine does not exist; if it would, then yes it would be that dangerous.

Comment: Astatine exists, just not for very long…

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141585/could-there-ever-be-a-way-to-safely-handle-visible-amounts-of-elements-like-asta

Comment: More reliable sources reckon there is a total amount of 45 milligrams in the earth's crust. The difference to "doesn't exist" is imo negligible. ;) https://ataridogdaze.com/science/As-Earth-crust.html Although if you had some magic to collect those 45 mg in your hand in one moment, you'de be indeed _dead_  in the next.

Comment: While his general point about the lower-down radioactive elements is completely right, there are several uncharacteristic errors in the chapter (though it is broadly correct despite them.) He calls ammonia an element; he confuses two different stories about russian defectors being killed (the one killed with polonium was poisoned via tea, the umbrella incident used ricin).

Comment: Is your question about the *entire chapter* (which is likely too broad as it would require a substantial amount of fact-checking), or just the astatine part? If it's the latter, could I encourage you to [edit] your question title & text to more clearly reflect that? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I'm reminded of a science fiction story about an intelligent, ant-like race, found on a planetoid far from it's sun. The workers were separating and collecting, in a circular amphitheater, each element, starting with an outer ring of frozen hydrogen, then liquid He, and so forth. A human explorer contacts and befriends the queen, in the amphitheater's center. He realizes she should stop before uranium, but she continues until the explosion destroys her... and lofts her eggs to colonize other planetoids.  Anyone know name or author?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't. Maybe Someone one Scifi.SE...

Comment: Randall does say (p.37 bottom) "the other half of the data is from [_Look Around You_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_Around_You), which was a mock-"educational" show presenting utter nonsense (in serious voice)...  Also keep in mind his disclaimer "I like when things catch fire and explode, which means I do not have your best interests in mind." elsewhere in the book